# How to train semantic role labeling with allennlp?

Tags: python, nlp, allennlp

Where is the training config file? The link on this page is dead https://demo.allennlp.org/semantic-role-labeling

> Training
> The SRL model was evaluated on the CoNLL 2012 dataset. Unfortunately we cannot release this data due to licensing restrictions by the LDC. You can put together evaluation data yourself by following the CoNLL 2012 instructions for working with the data. Once you have compiled the dataset, you can use the configuration file at https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/training_config/semantic_role_labeler.jsonnet to train.

Answer (score 1):

The training config for the SRL model can be found here: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/main/training_config/structured_prediction/bert_base_srl.jsonnet

The link on the demo page will be updated.